# MySQL SELECT all from first table and join matched data from second table with specific where clause for second table filter

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, where-clause

I have an issue when trying to fetch out my data from my database.

here are my table design

I have an issue when trying to fetch out my data from my database.

here are my table design

### table1:

```
user_id    username
1          test
2          test2
3          test3
```

### table2:

```
id         table2_userid   key        value
1          2               position   admin
2          2               name       myname
```

#### What i want to output is:

```
user_id     username       key        value
1           test           NULL       NULL
2           test2          position   admin
3           test3          NULL       NULL
```

#### This is my current sql code:

```
 SELECT table1.user_id, table1.username, table2.key, table2.value 
 FROM table1 
 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.table2_userid WHERE table2.key="position"
```

However, this return nothing. Please help me in this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is at the WHERE clause. Forcing key='position' eliminates null results. Try WHERE table2.key="position" or table2.key is NULL

Comment: that way wont work as well. The solution that Robin Saxena and M Khalid Junaid solve the problem. Thanks btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following Query it will work for your problem:

```
SELECT table1.user_id, table1.username, table2.key, table2.value FROM 
table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.table2_userid and 
table2.key="position" group by table1.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes:

```
SELECT table1.user_id, table1.username, table2.key, table2.value 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.table2_userid WHERE table2.key = 'position'
```

Otherwise your query seems fine to me.

I've read this on SO in a comment: `[S]ingle for [S]trings; [D]ouble for [D]atabase`

Answer (score 0):

Move your condition from where clause to on clause

```
SELECT 
t1.user_id, 
t1.username, 
t2.key, 
t2.value 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.user_id = t2.table2_userid 
AND t2.key="position"
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dc32/7)

Comment: Yours works as well. thanks. However i got the answer from Robin Saxena first so i cant choose your as my answer. sorry and thanks a lot :D